# UIView with drop shadow - slow when applying renderInContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, uigraphicscontext

I am capturing the contents of a `UIView` into a `UIImage` using `view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. The view is `UICollectionView` and I have added shadows to each cell in the following way:

```
cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
cell.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:cell.bounds].CGPath;
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Conversion to `UIImage` goes as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, 0, 0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The trouble is that while the the initial display of the cells seems fast enough, when I capture the snapshot of the view, the addition of the shadows slows down the performance by 10-30 times, depending on the shadow radius. On an iPad 2, it goes from 70 ms with no shadows, to full 2 seconds with 3px shadows!

I have read that setting `layer.shadowPath` should help with performance, but I actually do not see any appreciable difference in speed whether it is set or not.

What can I do to speed up the rendering on the snapshot in this case? The cells are not guaranteed to be any specific size so unfortunately I cannot use a pre-rendered image to fake a shadow effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderInContext:` *is* slow. That is why iOS 7 adds the UIView snapshotting methods (such as `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`). Use them where possible; they are much faster.

Comment: That is a great tip! I suppose it's tough luck for iOS 6?

Comment: I believe so. There are some WWDC videos on drawing performance, though; you might want to spend some time with them and see if they provide any useful ideas.